# Programming a Database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

The problem I have been provided is:

Write the DDL to construct the Facebook User and Post tables in SQL server. You need to populate the user table with the user’s information provided as in Figure 1 and additional attributes may be needed for the design. Use the ID in the excel file to identify the other Facebook user. For example ID 612831408762037 is David Cunliffe. Import the excel sheets to SQL server and then write effective SQL to merge the two tables into the Post table.

The code I have written so far is:

```
IF EXISTS(
   SELECT *
   FROM sys.tables
   WHERE name = N'FacebookUser'
)
DROP TABLE FacebookUser;

IF EXISTS(
   SELECT *
   FROM sys.tables
   WHERE name = N'Post'
)
DROP TABLE Post;

CREATE TABLE FacebookUser
 (UserID varchar(15) primary key not null,
  UserName varchar(30) not null,
  UserDescript varchar(500),
  JoinDate date not null,
  HomeTown varchar(30),
  Affiliation varchar(30),
  Country varchar(30),
  CurrentOffice varchar(100),
  Gender varchar(6) not null,
  Email varchar(30),
  OtherAccounts varchar(100),
  Website varchar(500),
 );

CREATE TABLE Post
 (id char(28) not null,
  message varchar(8000) not null,
  type varchar(15) not null,
  created_time datetime not null,
  updated_time datetime not null,
  shares.count int not null,
  count of likes.name int not null, 
  count of comments.message int not null, 
  Link varchar(50) not null,
  name varchar(50) not null,
  Description varchar(200) not null,
 );

INSERT INTO FacebookUser
VALUES('612831408762037', 'Some Name', 'Some very long text to insert in my row just for test cases',
    '02/18/2009', 'New Lynn/Auckland', 'New Zealand Labour Party', 'New Zealand', 'Office: Member of Parliament for New Lynn Party: New Zealand Labour Party', 'Male',
    'Mailadress@example.com', 'Some Name (Other Service)', 'www.example.com');

INSERT INTO FacebookUser
VALUES('1119736203', 'Another Name', 'Some other example text, with some extend ', '02/20/2008', NULL, 
    NULL, 'New Zealand', 'Office: Prime Minister Party: NZ National Party', 'Male', 'a.someone@example.com', NULL, 
    'http://example.com');
```

I have imported the data, but am unsure how merge the data into the second table, and I get errors on these lines of code:

```
shares.count int not null,
  Link varchar(50) not null,
  name varchar(50) not null,
  Description varchar(200) not null,
```

I'm completely lost from here. Is anybody able to help?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use square brackets for field names which are keywords or containing spaces or invalid characters

```
      [shares.count] int not null,
      [count of likes.name] int not null, 
      [count of comments.message] int not null,
```

In addition you will have to make sure that the fields are big enough to keep the values you want to store, other ways you will get errors like `String or binary data would be truncated.`